# What is the difference between a Local Database in C# and a SQL Server Management Studio created database?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-c#-express-2010, local-database

I'm creating an application with MS Visual C# 2010 Express that requires a database.

I've learned that there seem to be two ways to create/use a SQL database with this application.

The first seems to be where from within C#, I can create a "local database" by right-clicking on my application in the Solution Explorer and clicking "Add"->"New Item"->"Local Database". Then it's shown in the Database Explorer and I can use it.

The other way is where I create a database with SQL Server Management Studio and then from within the C# code, I open a connection to it (SQLConnection... yada yada yada) and use it.

I'm having a hard time understanding what technical reasons there are between choosing one way or the other way to do this...

Can someone describe the differences and what criteria would be used to choose one way vs. the other?  (or point to a website reference...)

Thanks!

-Adeena

Additional Info... 
Right now, this is really a hobby project as I get a few things worked out.

1. I'm the only developer and working on a single machine
2. The application is intended to be one that runs standalone - not in a
   browser or over the web in any way. I know that that's not the direction
   the universe is heading, but as mentioned above, this is a hobby
   project that I need to complete to work out a few other issues.
3. I don't believe I have any need or intent for multiple applications to
   work on this database.

Comment: I believe the `Add New Item -> Local Database` will add an instance of a SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) database (a single .sdf file) to your project. This is an "embedded", single-user local database - it's **NOT** SQL Server Express (and **not** a server product)!

Answer (score 14):

Actually you have *three* options. The option you didn't describe is the one where you create a database with SSMS and then set up a connection *to a file* and select the MDB file that was created by SSMS (you will probably need to first dismount the database using SSMS to get SQL Express to release its file locks). When you created this connection to a file, you will be prompted as to whether you want to connect to it where it is, or add it to your project.

A local database can take two forms, depending on how you create it. For detailed information, consult [How to: Manage Local Data Files in Your Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx).

**Client-server, SQL Express**

If you set up a database with SSMS and connect to it via SQL Express then you don't have a local database that's part of your project, you have a database for which the server happens to be local to your workstation.

**Local database, SQL Express**

If you set up a database with SSMS, dismount the database and add the file to your project, then you have a local database that uses a private instance of SQL Express.

**Local database, Compact Edition**

If you create a new database with the Visual Studio menus, you have a local Compact Edition database .

### SQL Express

When Visual Studio launches debugging, a private named instance of SQL Server Express is started, and the application communicates with this using shared memory rather than a network protocol.

However, there is absolutely nothing preventing you from installing an instance of SQL Express that runs as a service. You can mount the same database file (or a copy of it) and make it available to the network. You can even mount it on an instance of SQL Standard, or even SQL Enterprise.

Why then would you muck about with a local instance? It has advantages for multi-developer teams because developers can alter their schema without disrupting others. It allows development of desktop (as opposed to network) software, although in this day and age demand for that capability is diminishing.

Depending on how much hardware you have in your development environment, personally I wouldn't use a local database. SQL Server is a memory pig, and I'd much rather it ran on a completely separate box.

Some things to note

- TSQL is absolutely identical for all editions of MSSQL except for the Compact and Micro editions.
- Environmentally, SQL Express limits database size to 4G although I believe this went up to 8G for R2. This is unlikely to be significant for development but may impact testers.
- Some SQL Server Reporting Services features are not available in cheaper editions.

### SQL Server Compact Edition

Information on this is pretty thin. Microsoft's version comparison doesn't consider Compact or Micro editions. Some of the blurb on the Compact edition web page claims full TSQL compatibility. SDF is an all-in-one file; there is no separate log file. The path from SDF to client-server is certainly less direct than for SQL Express, but it does appear to be a supported option since there are articles in msdn on this topic.

Replication tools are available for Compact edition so that it can be used as a local database cache in an occasionally connected system (aka briefcase model). Briefcase model requires more careful total system design, but it has a lot going for it: all the performance and simplicity of a single user standalone system with most of the advantages of a client-server system.

### Conclusion

For your purposes I'd go with the Compact Edition option. The overheads and complexity of the other solutions are pitched at solving problems you don't and won't have. They are intended to solve the problems of team development in a networked, large scale environment with a formal release cycle.

You are in the fortunate position that you *can* keep it simple. The tools in Visual Studio are nicer anyway.

Comment: I believe the `Add New Item -> Local Database` will add an instance of a SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) database (a single .sdf file) to your project. This is an "embedded", single-user local database - it's **NOT** SQL Server Express (and **not** a server product)!

Comment: @Peter can we deploy later on a "local CE sql server"?

Comment: Deploy to where? If you are hoping that a setupkit can deploy the application and a CE database into progfiles\appfolder then yes you can; this is the primary purpose of the CE technology.

Comment: @PeterWone in terms of version control of this application, how feasible it is to use compact edition? After deploying and installation user will start filling data into their version. Later how can we update the versions?

Comment: CE has the same problems as Enterprise in respect of version control. Much as I dislike Redgate I suggest you buy their product, it's the only practical way to version control a database. You can use it to compare your updated database with what the customer has and generate data preserving schema update scripts.

Answer (score 0):

A local database uses a scaled down version of SQL Server - the <strike>Express</strike> compact edition (CE). There's a number of technical limitations, but the most important one is that a local database is only available to the instance the application runs in. A database server on the other hand can be accessed by other applications, or other instances of the same application. In effect, shared by multiple users who all see the same data.

Comment: The question is using one app to create a database verses the other; not the difference between a local installation of SQL Server and a higher version on a server.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for your take on it. I'll let @adeena weigh in before I either edit or delete my answer. It does seem to me like the question is whether to use a VS-created database or one from SSMS. The difference mainly comes down to accessibility, which I tried to touch upon.

Comment: I believe the `Add New Item -> Local Database` will add an instance of a SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) database (a single .sdf file) to your project. This is an "embedded", single-user local database - it's **NOT** SQL Server Express (and **not** a server product)!

Comment: Thanks!  I added some more details on my intended use to the original post above.  At least for this application - which is meant to run standalone on a single machine - accessibility isn't an issue.  But I'll keep that in mind for future applications in which it might be...

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, you're right on CE and not Express. In the end the important part is that it's not a server as you mentioned...it runs in process **with** your application.

Answer (score 0):

To get a more detailed view of what is happening: look at the settings and other features of the [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) statement. I don't know exactly, but one application may use different default setting. Read further in the article for how the 'model' database plays into this.